# replacing createStore with configureStore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I updated my packages and VScode told me that createStore was depreciated. So I went about replacing it

My store file, I have included the original line as a comment at the bottom

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Action, createStore } from 'redux'

export type State = { context: AudioContext | null}

export const START_AUDIO = "startAudio";

const initialState = {context: null}
  
const reducer = (state: State = initialState, action: Action<String>) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case START_AUDIO:
            if (state.context == null) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    context: new AudioContext()
                }
            }
    }
    return state
}

export const Store = configureStore({reducer})
// export const Store = createStore(reducer)
```

Using redux

```
export function AudioContext() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<Action<String>>>();
    const context = useSelector((state: State) => state.context)
    return (
        <button disabled={(context == null) ? false : true} onClick={() => dispatch({type: START_AUDIO}) }>Start Audio Context</button>
    )
}
```

App component

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Store } from '../code/util/store/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (<>
    <Head>
      <title>Test App</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  </>)
}
```

With `configureStore()` the console is giving me a [warning about putting non-serizible objects in state](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state). They say its possible but when I try to use it i get a `Maximum call stack size` error.

I have tried removing other uses (apart from setting it) of the redux state object and I still got both errors, I have also tried using a string, this removes the warning and the error. So it would seem that using an `AudioContext` in state isn't supported any longer for whatever reason.

Am I doing this wrong? Should I stop using Redux for this? How else can I achieve this?

I found this [issue on github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2036) however, according to my `node_modules` im running `7.18.0` of `@babel/core`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, Redux is a state management tool - state meaning pretty much: data. Usually that data should be represented as a plain JavaScript object or array, not a class instance.

What you are doing here is more of a "dependency injection" use case: you have a certain class with provided functionality that you want to pass down to child components.

In this case I'd recommend you to use React Context, as Context is a dependency injection mechanism (but not very suited for state value propagation - but that's nothing you want to do here in the first place).